# is there any way to use the path argument in extra_context dict in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have an url into my url patterns like this:

`path("object_edit/<id>/",TemplateView.as_view("object_edit.html")`

There is any way to use the `<id>` argument in the pattern to pass it as extra_context to the template?

Comment: Do you talk about that `id`? `TemplateView` passes all the captured arguments to the context already so you shouldn't need to do anything more if that is what you want.

Comment: Yes, is about that id, but if I want to show it in the template with ```{{id}}``` it doesn't show the value.

Comment: It works perfectly for me though. Please provide a [mre]. Show your other url patterns it may be that instead of this pattern your url is matching some earlier pattern in the list and that view is being used.

Comment: Thanks, as you say it was matching in another pattern. It works perectly!